# Unity Character controller bouncing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, controller, fbx, animator

I have a game object with a Character controller. I set it up to move and jump. Everything works fine, but when I add an Animator, the object  bounces once after landing on some other object that contains the box collider.

I have already tried many ways, but they did not lead to a positive result. I tried to edit the fbx model, change the anchor point, change the position of the Character controller on the object.

When I removed the animator, the problem disappeared, but I need to use movement animation. And for some reason it affects gravity. Without it, the player's game object jumps higher. I've been working in Unity not so long ago and I don't remember how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the RigidBody component, you may need to make a physics material for your player. The physics material defines some properties of the object such as how much it bounces. In the Assets folder: click create > physic material

This will create a physics material. Edit the bounciness and add it to the RigidBody of your character.